# How do I Object.assign() default values to another partly complete object only for hasOwnProperty false properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, properties, default

**Updated Question Title & Description - 17th February 2017**

Is there an effective function that fills an object's only missing properties compared to a default object properties and values?

I'm currently working on a bot class that retrieves a JSON API by update web calls. `Object.assign(targetObj, sourceObj)` has helped a lot but wondering if there was another method like it.

```
function (result) {
    // default properties if they don't exist inside result object
    const defaults = {
        from: {
            id: NaN,
            username: ""
        }
    };

    // Example "from" may not exist at all in the result object.
    // Maybe "from" does exist in result and provides only an "id",
    // but I don't want to overwrite the "id" and still provide
    // the "username" with a default value if there isn't one.
}
```

I thought about multiple if conditioning `hasOwnProperty` but I'm wondering is there a better way than a table of if conditions like Object.assign()?

I don't want to require another script or use npm for this.

Comment: Best way I know to do a deep clone is [lodash's _.cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#cloneDeep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been going through my code snippets and trying to build the functionality I wanted. I've managed to succeed after many hours.

**Return a new target object without harming the original.**

```
function defaultsDeep(target, defaults) {
    var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(target));
    function run(clone, defaults) {
        const DEFAULTS_PROPERTY_NAMES = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(defaults);
        DEFAULTS_PROPERTY_NAMES.forEach(function (property) {
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(defaults[property]) === "[object Object]") {
                if (!clone.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                    clone[property] = {};
                }
                run(clone[property], defaults[property]);
            } else if (!clone.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                clone[property] = defaults[property];
            }
        });
    }
    run(clone, defaults);
    return clone;
}
```

**Example**

```
var result = {
    "message_id": 1,
    "from": {
        "id": 12345
    }
};

const defaults = {
    "from": {
        "id": null,
        "username": ""
    }
};

var newObj = defaultsDeep(result, defaults);
console.log("newObj " + JSON.stringify(newObj));
/* result
{
    "message_id": 1,
    "from": {
        "id": 12345,
        "username": ""
    }
}
*/
```

I don't know if there's a better way of coding this. But if there is, feel free to edit. Also, if you're wondering why I didn't use `for in` loop method. It's because jslint discourages it now in es6 and I don't think I can disable the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Like Julian Soro said in the comments I think the best way to do this is through lodash. They even have a defaultsDeep function

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#defaultsDeep

Comment: I think that's exactly what I'm after. Is there a non-npm version made function that does the same task? I don't want to include other libraries in my class except the node built-in ones.

Comment: If you are using any node modules you might already have lodash. I would strongly consider using it. Its not that big and contains a lot of nifty functions that are very useful